# Why does flatMap take in a function that returns stream instead of Collection?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream, functional-interface

Why does the flatMap operation require a function which returns Stream instead of a function that returns a Collection? Any particular reason it forces the user to do the stream conversion manually?

Reading the source code example I can see that this way the compatibilioty can be extended to arrays but wouldn't an overload of flatMap achieve the same result?

```
// Java 8 source code example:
Stream<String> words = lines.flatMap(line -> Stream.of(line.split(" +")));
```

What are the use cases where it's better to have the streaming process explicited?

Example: why am I forced to do this

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> flatList = map.entrySet().stream().flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

instead of this?

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> flatList = map.entrySet().stream().flatMap(Map.Entry::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: maybe¹ because `flatMap` itself is intended to be used on `Stream`, kind of being consistent - one characteristics of `Stream` is to only run portions that are needed when and if they are needed - creating a collection would avoid that. || **¹** I am not one of the developers nor specifier, it would be better ask someone involved in its development

Comment: What if you'd want to return another stream that's not represented as an array or collection? Let's say I want to manually split an object into a stream of values - sure, I could create a collection first but that might be overhead. Just requiring to return a stream is very flexible and tbh not that much more complex.

Comment: Streams and collections are not interchangeable. But you can stream any collection, so it makes sense to accept the more flexible construct.

Comment: @Thomas yes it doesn't add much more code, was just wondering why it was designed to be this way, because most of the time it just forces me to write an extra .stream(), I guess your argument does make sense, thanks!

Comment: Streaming over another collection doesn’t seem to be the intended primary use case, at least, the implementation is not optimized for this scenario. It works best with rather small sub-streams, which might be derived from collections but could also stem from a function like `arg -> condition? Stream.of(x, y, z): null` or `arg -> condition? Stream.of(arg): Stream.of(arg, anotherObject)` By the way, instead of `.flatMap(line -> Stream.of(line.split(" +")))`, I’d rather use `.flatMap(Pattern.compile(" +")::splitAsStream)`

Comment: In my experience, it's frequently used with collections, but often there are additional operations before flattening, e.g. `.flatMap(list -> list.stream().limit(3))`

Comment: Btw, in case you find it cleaner, you can replace `.flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream())` with `.map(Entry::getValue).flatMap(List::stream)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the `flatMap()` operation require a function which returns `Stream` instead of a function that returns a `Collection`?

There are many reasons for that:

- Stream is a **means of iteration**, i.e. we're not storing the data in the stream, its purpose is to iterate *lazily* many over the source of data, which can be a `String`, Array, IO-Stream, etc.
- Secondly, Stream operations are divided into two groups: ***terminal***, which are meant to produce the result and terminate the execution of the stream pipeline (i.e. it's not possible to apply any operation after a terminal one), and ***intermediate*** operations, which transform the stream. Intermediate operations are always **lazy**. A stream takes elements from the source one-by-one and processes them *lazily*, i.e. operations occur only when needed. Don't a new stream with a chain of nested `for`-loops, they act differently. Every intermediate operation produces a new stream.

Here's a quote from the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

> Streams differ from collections in several ways:
>
> - **No storage**. A stream is **not a data structure** that stores elements; instead, it conveys elements from a source such as a data structure,
>   an array, a generator function, or an I/O channel, through a pipeline
>   of computational operations.
> - **Laziness-seeking**. Many stream operations, such as filtering, mapping, or duplicate removal, can be implemented lazily, exposing
>   opportunities for optimization. For example, "find the first String
>   with three consecutive vowels" need not examine all the input strings.
>   Stream operations are divided into intermediate (Stream-producing)
>   operations and terminal (value- or side-effect-producing) operations.
>   Intermediate operations are **always lazy**.

- Since Stream are internal iterators over the source of data which can have a different nature (*not necessarily a* `Collectoin`) it's reasonable for `flatMap()` to expect data in a predictable **uniform shape**, not an Array, Collection, Iterable, etc. but another internal iterator, i.e. another Stream, so that's obvious how to deal with it.

Any option that you can up with would be less intuitive. If `flatMap()` was implemented in such a way so that it would expect a function producing `Collection` how would you deal with strings, arrays, IO-Streams, various implementations of `Iterable`? By dumping the data into a Collection - that's not an option. Same issue would arise if we imagine that `flatMap()` required `Iterable`, how would we produce `Iterable` from a `String`? Streams are designed to be versatile.

I suspect that your judgement regarding `flatMap()` is biased because you are not accustomed to it. When you embrace the idea that a **Stream is an Internal Iterator**, the fact that operation for flattening the data expect function producing another iterator would be perceived as more intuitive.